# Modelling data with swift enums

Tags: swift, enums, minecraft, data-modeling

This is more of a software design than a coding question, but then isn't that always the actual hard problem ? Anyway, I'm trying to model Minecraft's [NBT Format](https://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/NBT_format#Data_types) in order to read / write its save files.

I'm pretty sure using enums is the best choice here : There are a limited number of cases, which shouldn't be alterable by the user, and all need to be dealt with. Also, as you will see below, one problematic case is very hard to model any other way.

However, NBT data can be *nested*, of course, and can also contain lists of any single NBT type. That includes lists of lists, where things like `[[Int],[Double]]` are legal (the contained types are both lists, NBT doesn't enforce anything past that point). Basically, a list can only contain a single tag type, but lists of anything are all considered the same type.

And yes, the duplicate way of storing some types of arrays is part of the spec. A `[Int8]` can be stored either as `byteArray` or `List<Byte>`, that much is expected. Hence also the previous use of the word List instead of Array : those are two different but similar things in NBT.

I have coded this for now, which works perfectly well, but I fear probably has some glaring design flaws I'm not experienced enough to notice :

```swift
public enum Tag : Equatable {
    
    case end
    case byte(Int8)
    case short(Int16)
    case int(Int32)
    case long(Int64)
    case float(Float)
    case double(Double)
    case byteArray([Int8])
    case string(String)
    case list(TagList)
    case compound([String : Tag])
    case intArray([Int32])
    case longArray([Int64])
}

public enum TagList : Equatable {

    case end
    case byte([Int8])
    case short([Int16])
    case int([Int32])
    case long([Int64])
    case float([Float])
    case double([Double])
    case byteArray([[Int8]])
    case string([String])
    case list([List])
    case compound([[String : Tag]])
    case intArray([[Int32]])
    case longArray([[Int64]])
}
```

Is there a saner way to do this ? I'm really not a fan of repeating basically the same enum cases twice, but because of the `Tag.List.list` case they can't be merged (because for there to be a list of list, lists must be defined apart from the rest).

Comment: Maybe this could be better resolved with generics, `Tag<NBTType>`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I have thought about this, however the hard problem in this case is the "list of list" thing : If I want a list like `[[1, 2],["a", "b"]]` which is valid in `NBT`, Swift will refuse to let that conform to the `NBTType` protocol, because it has to be declared as `[any NBTType]`, which cannot conform to the protocol at the same time as `[some NBTType]`(aka `Array where Element : NBTType`) because of limitations to extensions.

Comment: `NBTType` is not a protocol in my example, it is just the name of the generic type (instead of something like T).

Comment: I'm not sure how the restrictions would be enforced then ? For example `Tag<ZStack>` would be inappropriate, how would you prevent that in your solution ?

Comment: It's a suggestion and not a solution, I haven't read the documentation you linked to so I don't know much about the types or your use case for that matter so I just offered something to consider.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about the domain, but can you do something like:

```
public enum TagStyle<T> {
    .value(T)
    .list([T])
}

public enum Tag : Equatable {

    case end
    case byte(TagStyle<Int8>)
    case short(TagStyle<Int16>)
    case int(TagStyle<Int32>)
    case long(TagStyle<Int64>)
    case float(TagStyle<Float>)
    case double(TagStyle<Double>)
    case byteArray(TagStyle<Data>)
    case string(TagStyle<String>)
    case list(TagStyle<List>)
    case compound(TagStyle<[String : Tag]>)
    case intArray(TagStyle<[Int32]>)
    case longArray(TagStyle<[Int64]>)
}
```

Comment: In the case of `Tag.list`, did you set it to `TagStyle<TagList>` on purpose ? That does imply the `TagList` enum still exists, in which case I'm not sure what is fundamentally different with your proposition.

Comment: Looks like a mistake on my part.  I guess that should be `case list(TagStyle<List>)`